# I am creating a blog app using Java. Do I set Id manually or Auto generate in Mysql DB?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

I see most people recommend saying let the DB generate the ID. How do I access the post then?  Let's say, I click on button to delete a comment, NOW, how do I know this comment belongs to which posts id?

```
public interface PostService {
    Long createPost(String title, String content, List categories, Date publishing_date);
    Long createComment(String author, String content, Date submission_date);
    List getAllPosts();
    List getAllCommentsOn(Long post);
    boolean existPost(Long post);
}
```

Comment: use a primary key with an `AUTO_INCREMENT` to auto-assign numeric ids. Retrieval based on fields/attributes is done just by selection around the other columns. e.g. `SELECT foo.* .... WHERE foo.my_column = 'bar'`

Comment: What do you mean? You can access anything in the db without knowing the id? (Well except you can't query by id). But you can have a field with a column with the name like most-commented-post and query with that in mind, i.e return the post which have the highest value in that column

Comment: The id is the least of your problems.  You can't find the most commented post using it.  You'll have to understand SQL, relational databases, and JOINs.

Comment: `most-commented-post` is an example. I have different scenarios such as getting comments for each post and deleting comment for particular post. So for this, I need to have a unique id always right?

Answer (score 0):

This is not mandatory, but I suggest you to use an `Auto Increment` column and make it `PRIMARY KEY`. This help you in maintaining a primary as well as unique column manually as well as speed up your SELECT query because of `PRIMARY KEY` index.

Answer (score 0):

I would let it auto generate. Then query for the "most-commented-post"

"select * from Posts order by CommentsCount desc limit 1"

and get it with the ID.

Comment: `most-commented-post` is an example. I have different scenarios such as getting comments for each post and deleting comment for particular post. So for this, I need to have a unique id always right?

Comment: Yes but not always, you could delete all Posts without comments for Example - for this you do not need an id. But to delete a specific one you need to get the id first, and this could be achieved with the select. Attach your database schema and ask for an example

Comment: with select, It would be selecting all the rows to get the id?

Comment: well "limit 1" will return one element. You need then to handle the case when multiple posts have the same comments count - this depends on your business logic

Comment: I think you have misunderstood. Let's say, I click on button to delete a comment, NOW, how do I know this comment belongs to which posts id?

Comment: you need to have a relation to the post. Any comment should point to the id of a post. Your Comments Table: "commentId, commentText, createdOn, createdFrom, postId" where postId ist the ForeignKey to your Posts Table.

Comment: I know about pk_fk relation. But how do know which post `id` to pass in this case: `/delete_comment/:id` when I click on delete button??

Comment: i guess this is a restful request? So you have the Id of the comment? Comment can be deleted without getting the post. But if you need the post, then query the comment from the database and get the postId of the comment.

Comment: Yes. So I need to pass `id` when I click on button to delete the comment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138910/discussion-between-kiteup-and-kittu).

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer DB to generate it. you can modify your createComment method to accept

```
public interface PostService {
    Long createPost(String title, String content, List categories, Date publishing_date);
    Long createComment(Long postId,String author, String content, Date submission_date);
    List getAllPosts();
    List getAllCommentsOn(Long post);
    boolean existPost(Long post);
}
```

When someone is adding the comment on particular post you should definately have the post id as in hidden field at least.